# qemu extension for Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, qemu, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

I would like to have a Chrome extensión for qemu not only for having an HTML good front end.

It will allow Chromebooks to run other OSs without having to loose security.

It will also allow the Pixel to run Android virtualized with VGA passthrough what will make the Pixel one of the best tablets - in this case hybrid - in performance.

And without entering in developer mode use some software with any Ubuntu or Manjaro installation, and of course install MS WOS or even OSX for rare users.

From an almost mono OS to multi OS,and perhaps with the Android OS preinstalled - Samsung already does it with MS WOS 8 - and of course more brands will make hybrid chromebooks.

Comment: Have you tried compiling QEMU under NaCl ?

Comment: Sounds ambitious! Did you have a question?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need special extension to access QEMU virtual machine screen from Chrome - there are several VNC clients written in JavaScript, and QEMU supports VNC output.

For example [noVNC](http://kanaka.github.io/noVNC/) client works fine, if you don't forget to run websockets proxy. Something like

`qemu-system-i386 -hda /home/user/myhddimage.qcow2 -usbdevice tablet -vnc :3 &`

`cd /home/user/noVNC`

`./utils/websockify --web ./ 8783 localhost:5903 &`

`google-chrome file:///home/user/noVNC/vnc_auto.html?host=localhost&port=8783&encrypt=0&true_color=1`